# Tensorflow 2.0+ Unknown entries in loss dictionary when recovering saved model with tf.keras.models.load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Note: I am using a dockerized GPU TF environment (`tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0-gpu-py3-jupyter)

I have a `tf.keras` model initialized via the "functional" API, e.g.

```py
input = tf.keras.Input(...)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(...)(input)
...
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(..., name="logit_layer")(y)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, logits)
```

I then compile it with a custom loss:

```py
def my_loss(labels, logits):
    # here just wrapping a known loss to remove errors that could come from me
    # however there may be additional functionality here
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=labels,
        logits=logits
    )
    return loss

model.compile(
    ...,
    loss ={
        'logit_layer': my_loss
    },
)
```

I then proceed to train this model with `ModelCheckpoint` callbacks, and after training save it in a myriad of ways:

```py
model.save(...)
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, ...)
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, ...)
model.save_weights(...)
```

Now I try to load my saved model:

```
custom = {
    'my_loss': my_loss
}
model_file = # one of the files from above
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file, custom)
```

Each and every one of these models gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-52082d68b682> in <module>
      1 model_file = os.path.join(model_to_use)
----> 2 model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file, custom)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    145   if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):
    146     loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
--> 147     return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)
    148 
    149   raise IOError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in load(path, compile)
     91     if model._training_config is not None:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
     92       model.compile(**saving_utils.compile_args_from_training_config(
---> 93           model._training_config))  # pylint: disable=protected-access
     94 
     95   return model

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute, **kwargs)
    334     # Prepare list of loss functions, same size of model outputs.
    335     self.loss_functions = training_utils.prepare_loss_functions(
--> 336         self.loss, self.output_names)
    337 
    338     target_tensors = self._process_target_tensor_for_compile(target_tensors)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in prepare_loss_functions(loss, output_names)
   1337   """
   1338   if isinstance(loss, collections_abc.Mapping):
-> 1339     generic_utils.check_for_unexpected_keys('loss', loss, output_names)
   1340     loss_functions = []
   1341     for name in output_names:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in check_for_unexpected_keys(name, input_dict, expected_values)
    589     raise ValueError('Unknown entries in {} dictionary: {}. Only expected '
    590                      'following keys: {}'.format(name, list(unknown),
--> 591                                                  expected_values))
    592 
    593 

ValueError: Unknown entries in loss dictionary: ['logit_layer']. Only expected following keys: ['output_1']
```

I have found several github issues related to this:

1. https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/issues/481
2. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28059
3. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25938

The second issue claims to be duplicate of the third and seems different from what I do above.
The first issue, uses an actual layer to be the loss, and passes a permissive lambda function as the loss:

```py
lambda y_pred, y_true: y_pred
```

This does not seem the same as what I am doing.

How can I either:

1. load my model
2. change how I save my model so that I can load it

Comment: Seems like broken dockerized configuration, I was not able to reproduce issue using `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0`. If possible could you try this outside docker?

Comment: @VivekMehta can you try https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/neumf/blob/master/notebooks/NeuMF.ipynb of the corresponding repo?

Comment: I am getting page not found, probably repo is private?

Comment: @VivekMehta ah, sorry about that, try now

Answer (score 1):

The following codes works for me:

```
keras_model.save(model_dir)
...
keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir,compile=False)
```